# How is this tail recursive method being iterated?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

In below Scala method how is the List `xs` traversed by method `nth`? `xs.tail` is called recursively but why is the tail not always the same value since `def tail` in trait `List` just returns the list of parameterized types?

```
object nth {

  def nth[T](n: Int, xs: List[T]): T =
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    else if (n == 0) xs.head
    else {
        nth(n - 1, xs.tail)
        }                                 //> nth: [T](n: Int, xs: week4.List[T])T
  val list = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, new Nil)))
  nth(2 , list)   > res0: Int=3   
}

trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
}
class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = false
}
class Nil[T] extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = true
  def head : Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
  def tail : Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
}
```

Comment: you override head and tail in Cons with values and hence the result. the definition in the trait is abstract.

Comment: @aishwarya the tail is returning a List of [T] how are the list elements iterated over ?

Comment: the list here is not a list in true sense. Cons is an instance of List and thats what gets returned ;)

Comment: as pointed out by @aishwarya, the methods `isEmpty`, `head`, `tail`, defined in the `List[T]` _trait_, are _abstract_, and only define their return type. So the `tail` method should return an implementation of `List[T]`. `Cons` implements it by defining the `val tail` in its constructor params, and that's what's returned by calling `tail` on a `Cons` instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `List` is a recursive structure. See the [Wikipedia article on Cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons). This is from that article:

[image]

The structure you would begin with is `new Cons(42, new Cons(69, new Cons(613, new Nil)))`. Although the `tail` method also returns an instance of `List[Int]`, that is *not the same list*, but the sub-list that follows one of the right-pointing arrows.

So if in your example, you would start with `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))`, let `n` be `2`.

- In the **first** iteration of function `nth`, we ask: Is `Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))` empty? No! Is `n == 0`? No. So recurse with the tail and `n` decremented.
- In this **second** iteration, we ask: Is `Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil))` empty (this is again a `List[Int]`)? No. Is `n == 0`? No (it's `1` now). Go to the next recursion.
- In the **third** iteration, we ask: Is `Cons(3, Nil)` empty? No. Is `n == 0`. Yes! Therefore, return the head of `Cons(3, Nil)` which is `3`.

Comment: "Although the tail method also returns an instance of List[Int], that is not the same list, but the sub-list that follows one of the right-pointing arrows." Ok, but how does the sub list get returned ? Is there some implicit functionality moving the pointer forward ?

Comment: Nothing implicit. The call is `xs.tail` in `nth(n - 1, xs.tail)`. That's the "pointer move", you go from `xs` to `xs.tail`. For a non-empty List, **which is a Cons cell**, this returns the sub-list (`val tail`). For an empty List (`Nil`) it would throw an exception.

Comment: I did'nt realise that the 'tail' method is whats is moving the pointer along as it each time its called it's dividing the list into a new head & tail. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your List type recursively. This means, that you are using another lists for creating new ones. Naturally you have to make the first List somehow, that's why you have defined Nil.

So you can create an empty list without other lists:

```
val empty = new Nil[Int]                  //> empty  : Nil[Int] = Nil@1f93f8
```

and you can create not empty lists using already created lists, if you have an n-1 size List, you can create an n size one, saying, that the new list is the same as the old one (tail), plus the new elem (head):

```
val oneSize = new Cons(1, empty)          //> oneSize  : Cons[Int] = Cons@b159eb
```

If you inspect oneSize's tail, it turns out that it is the same object as `empty`

```
oneSize.tail                              //> res0: List[Int] = Nil@1f93f8
```

Let's define a list with 2 elems, using the oneSize list:

```
val twoSize = new Cons(2, oneSize)        //> twoSize  : Cons[Int] = Cons@18654ae
```

Inspecting the tail we get the oneSize list:

```
twoSize.tail                              //> res1: List[Int] = Cons@b159eb
```

so using tail again we have to get the empty list again as before, and indeed:

```
twoSize.tail.tail                         //> res2: List[Int] = Nil@1f93f8
```

Et voila, we've just iterated through the list, just as your nth function.